# Wordpress adding data to table (database)

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have a custom table in my WordPress database named "post_votes" used for voting posts.

Whenever I publish a new post can I simultaneously add some data to that table as well?

I'm trying to achieve this without editing any wp core files. Perhaps a function if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to register a function in your plugin to this action hook:

[{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/%7B%24new_status%7D_%7B%24post-%3Epost_type%7D)

Comment: Paul thanks for the link!! I'm finally appointed in right direction! I never used hooks before, would you please give a hint know how to add to a table via that?

Comment: Sure, you'll build a function that, when invoked by that action hook, will execute whatever code you need to inside your plugin to add data to your table.  As you can see from that link, the hook will pass post ID and the post object itself to your function (be sure your function takes two args), so you can pull out whatever data you want regarding the post.

Comment: Ahh so I'll just add an INSERT to table in the function Thanks :)